# Querying an indexed MySQL table with 67156 Rows, checks 162880 Rows, Does index not work?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance, sql-optimization

I query `wp_posts` table in my database.

Current indexes are as below:

[image]

I run the followin query:

```
SELECT MIN(post_parent) 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE  post_type = 'product_variation' and post_parent > 365191;
```

it checks 162880 rows as you can see below:

[image]

However there the following query returns just 67156 rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE  post_type = 'product_variation' and post_parent > 365191;
```

So why my index is not working as I expected ?

**P.S:** post_parent is a `bigInt`

Answer (score 3):

Your index is "working", but it is not useful for this query.

Basically, one purpose of an index is to reduce the number of data pages that need to be read.  When have a query that reads 67,156 out of 162,880 rows, the optimizer figures that every data pages needs to be read *anyway*.  So, why bother using the index.

As a note, for this query:

```
SELECT MIN(post_parent)
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'product_variation' and post_parent > 365191;
```

The optimal index is on `wp_posts(post_type, post_parent)`.  I am guessing that this index would actually be used, because it is a covering index for the query.  So reading the index has advantages over reading the original data pages.

Answer (score 1):

Your index is "working", but it is **only partially** useful for this query.

You did not disclose the exact details of the `type_status_date` index, but based on the name I assume it indexes post type, post status, and post date fields, in this particular order.

This means that `type_status_date` can only be used to narrow down the results based on post type, but cannot be used for looking up post parent, since the latter field is not part of the index. Mysql can only use a single index for a table in a query.

If you executed a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE  post_type = 'product_variation'
```

query, then the count will probably be a lot closer to the scanned rows count in the explain.

As Gordon explained, an index on post type, post parent fields would be more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

- The "Rows" in `EXPLAIN` are an approximation; sometimes very far off.
- `INDEX(post_type, post_parent)` is not only 'covering' (meaning that all the necessary columns are found in the index), but, together with `MIN()`, it will look at only one row to give the answer.
- Explain will indicate "covering" by saying "Using index" (not "Using index condition").
- `EXPLAIN` does not always lower the "Rows" to account for `LIMIT`, `MIN`, etc.  So, again, you can't always trust it.  See this for an accurate count:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts